# IntelliJ IDEA can't open *.cfg files

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-idea2017

*.cfg files in Idea won't open after restart.  [Here's the way they are indented in *Project* window.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEmYw.png)

I'm pretty much sure that files are not corrupted, as they do nicely open in notepad. Also, any other types of files open easily, it's just for *.cfg's.

I've tried to reload IDEA, and invalidate cache, no result. 
IDEA 2017.2.7 Community.

Any advices would be appreciated. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like some custom plugin is installed and associated with *.cfg files. Please try to disable custom plugins in "Settings | Plugins".

Comment: That helped. In my case it was Twelf Plugin. Thanks for advice.